# Не получается подписать метод на событие. C#

Tags: c#, события

Компилятор выдает ошибку "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект.". Вот код:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate int BinaryOp(int x, int y);
    public event BinaryOp Go;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Go += Add;
    }

    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Как это исправить ?

Answer (score 5):

Вы не можете обращаться из статического метода (в вашему случае `Main`) к нестатическим членам класса.

```
class Program
{
    public delegate int BinaryOp(int x, int y);
    public static event BinaryOp Go;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Go += Add;
    }

    public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Все статические поля хранятся в так называемом объект-типе от которого порождаются конкретные объекты. Сам объект-тип ничего не знает о нестатических полях конкретного объекта и не имеет к ним доступа.

При компиляции, вместо события `event BinaryOp Go` компилятор создаст приватное *поле* с типом делегата `BinaryOp` и два метода доступа к этому полю `add` и `remove` которые, соответственно, будут вызываться, когда вы добавляете новый обработчик события `Go += Add` или удаляете его `Go -= Add`.